# Cosmos DB Result Missing in Larger Search

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb

I wonder if I may be hitting a limit of some kind that is causing this behvaviour. I have run a query that proves a record exists in the Cosmos DB document collection when filtered by three fields PLUS the unique id, but when I remove the unique id I get back 124 results, none of which is the original record.

If I run the following live query in the Azure portal, I get a single result, which is the item I expect:

```
-- 1 result, item 'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP' present and correct
SELECT
    *
FROM a
WHERE a.width = 205
AND a.height = 55
AND a.depth = 16
AND a.uniqueId = 'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP'
```

When I remove the final line, I get *124* results, but not the item with unique id 'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP'.

```
-- 124 results, item 'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP' missing
SELECT
    *
FROM a
WHERE a.width = 205
AND a.height = 55
AND a.depth = 16
```

Each record is actually pretty big, because the document contains quite a large array of information. If I change the query again to:

```
-- 150 results, item 'ABCD-EFGH-IJKL-MNOP' present and correct
SELECT 
    a.width,
    a.height,
    a.depth,
    a.uniqueId
FROM a
WHERE a.width = 205
AND a.height = 55
AND a.depth = 16
```

I get *150* results and the result magically pops back into the results...

Is there some limit that could cause by result to be left out?

Additional notes:

1. I'm testing this in query explorer
2. I have changed "Settings -> Items per page" to "Unlimited"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though you run a query "unlimited" (with `FeedOptions.MaxItemCount` set to `-1`), the results can still be paged based on the amount of data that comes back.

You can detect this because the flag `Has More Results` comes back `true`:

```
if (queryable.HasMoreResults)
{
    //... there are more results
}
```

You may not be expecting this when running an unlimited query.

If you are using the REST API, there is a header for this:

```
x-ms-continuation=randomlookingstring
```

You can pass this header back in a subsequent request and the query will resume.

I am currently looking for the documentation on limits and will update when I find it.